# Mongodb projection for field selection is not working

Tags: mongodb

Here is the windows cli command `mongo --quiet alg --eval "printjson(db.lvfirstnames.find({},{"nameid":0}).limit(3).toArray())" > output.json` that gives following result:

```
    [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5836cf174dfc224da02a0da1"),
        "nameid" : 1,
        "name" : "Laimnesis",
        "NameDayDate" : 1.01
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5836cf174dfc224da02a0da2"),
        "nameid" : 3,
        "name" : "Miervaldis",
        "NameDayDate" : 3.01
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5836cf174dfc224da02a0da3"),
        "nameid" : 2,
        "name" : "Indulis",
        "NameDayDate" : 2.01
    }
]
```

Question: I'm not selecting "nameid" `{"nameid":0}` but why is the field still shown in output?

Comment: does excluding any other field work for you ??

Comment: Yes. For name field it works.

Comment: What is the `alg` argument? that seems to be breaking my output/

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following and worked

```
mongo --quiet --eval "printjson(db.lvfirstnames.find({},{"nameid":0}).limit(3).toArray())" > output.json
```

output.json

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5836cf174dfc224da02a0da1"),
        "name" : "Laimnesis",
        "NameDayDate" : 1.01
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5836cf174dfc224da02a0da2"),
        "name" : "Miervaldis",
        "NameDayDate" : 3.01
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5836cf174dfc224da02a0da3"),
        "name" : "Indulis",
        "NameDayDate" : 2.01
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you still have issue regarding this then try:

```
find({ } , {fields: { nameid : 0 }})
```

Hope it will be helpful for you.